# Is it possible to unreserve the reserved letters in SymPy Such as sympy.E and make it a sympy.Symbol?

Tags: python, sympy

Let's say for some reason you need or you prefer to have E or any of other reserved letters of SymPy as a symbol. So when you ask sympy.sympify("E"), you want a `<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>` not a `<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Exp1'>`. For a simple small example look at the following code.

```py
import sympy
symbols_list = sympy.symbols(' '.join(["A","E","Y"]))
expr = sympy.sympify("Y + 2 * E")
print(f"variables in expr are {expr.free_symbols}")
for x in symbols_list:
    print(f"coefficient of {x} in expr is {expr.coeff(x)}")
```

Then the printed message is

```
variables in expr are {Y}
coefficient of A in expr is 0
coefficient of E in expr is 0
coefficient of Y in expr is 1
```

while I want to see

```
variables in expr are {Y, E}
coefficient of A in expr is 0
coefficient of E in expr is 2
coefficient of Y in expr is 1
```

Is there anyway to force SymPy like declaring something at the beginning of the script to forget its own E in this script?

Comment: Can't you use a different variable name and just change it to `E` during printing?

Comment: @kinshukdua As the question states, it is about when someone for some reason does not want to use those tricks. ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `parse_expr` directly rather than `sympify` to customise the behaviour of the parser. With `parse_expr` you can specify the `local_dict` and `global_dict` to be used when executing the parsed code. In this case it is the `global_dict` that defines `E` but you can override that using the `local_dict`:

```
In [14]: parse_expr("Y + E", local_dict={'E':Symbol('E')}).free_symbols
Out[14]: {E, Y}
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr